# Why pointer will recover after exit functions?

Tags: c

I don't know how to exactly describe my confusion shortly in the title.

I have a piece of C code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun(int arr[]) {
printf("%d %p\n", arr[0], arr);
arr = arr+1; 
printf("%d %p\n", arr[0], arr);
}
int main(void) {
int arr[2] = {10, 20};
fun(arr);
printf("%d %p\n", arr[0], arr);
return 0;
}
```

Guess what is the output?

```
10 0x7ffe0a638520
20 0x7ffe0a638524
10 0x7ffe0a638520
```

Ok, so it seems the address did change in fun(), however, it recovered after exit the function.

Was this because the arr in fun() is only a copy of real arr in main()?

Comment: `int fun(int x) { x = x + 1; } int main(void) { int x = 5; fun(x); printf("%d\n", x); return 0; }` - what output do you expect that to produce?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Fair enough... I being stupid.

Comment: To be short, the base address of `arr` is being copied to a local pointer in `fun()` (function arguments can be treated as conveniently initialised local variables ). only local variable is modified here. hence the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that `int arr[]` is actually identical to `int* arr`.  In otherwords, arr is a copy of the value of the pointer passed to it from the first parameter of `fun()`.  I'm going to make some small changes to your code to make this clearer.  Specifically, I'm changing the name of `arr` in `fun()` so that it's clear that it's not the same `arr` as in `main()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun(int* ptr) {
    printf("%d %p\n", *ptr, ptr);
    ptr = ptr+1; 
    printf("%d %p\n", *ptr, ptr);
}
int main(void) {
    int arr[2] = {10, 20};
    fun(arr);
    printf("%d %p\n", arr[0], arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Now you can see that `arr` and `ptr` are completely independant.  `ptr` is a pointer that happens to point to the first element of `arr`.  If we change the value **at** `ptr`, then we'll change the original values of `arr`, but that's not what we're doing.  We are changing the value **of** `ptr` itself and since `ptr` is just a copy of `arr` and not the original value, it doesn't change the original.

I hope that's clear enough.

Comment: Hi Stewart, thanks for your reply. Now I understand.